# Would a large, small mass object in orbit experience induced rotation

Tags: energy-conservation, orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics, tidal-effect

Imagine a large (multiple earth radii), very small-mass ring orbiting The Sun. Half of the ring would be closer to The Sun than the outer half. Since orbital velocity decreases with distance, two free bodies would orbit at different velocities if placed in circular orbits at altitudes equal to each end of the ring.

But would the ring start rotating? Assuming no other forces, would the close part of the ring start orbiting faster, and the far part of the ring orbit (relatively) slower, inducing a "phantom" rotation from the point of view of an outside observer?

If yes, to what extent, how much rotational energy could be added to the system, and from where would it be coming from?

Comment: The dynamics you are getting at are those of [tidal forces](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-effect). In the frame of either body they are expressed as tensile forces along the axis joining the bodies and compressive forced transverse to that axis. They can induce rotation, but not on bodies that are symmetric around the shared axis (this is what causes tidal locking).